# How to insert n random NaN consecutive and no consecutive data by month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
       CODE      DATE     PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  0.0
1      000130 1991-01-02  1.0
2      000130 1991-01-03  2.0
3      000130 1991-01-04  2.0
4      000130 1991-01-05  1.1
      ...        ...  ...
10861  000142 2020-12-27  2.1
10862  000142 2020-12-28  2.2
10863  000142 2020-12-29  2.1
10864  000142 2020-12-30  0.4
10865  000142 2020-12-31  1.1
```

I want to have at least 3 consecutive nans and 5 non consecutive nans in `df['PP']` by each `df['CODE']` with their corresponding `df['DATE'].dt.year` and `df['DATE'].dt.month`
so i must convert random values of df['PP'] to NaN to reach that 3 consecutive and 5 non consecutive NaNs. Expected result:

```
       CODE      DATE     PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  0.0
1      000130 1991-01-02  NaN
2      000130 1991-01-03  NaN
3      000130 1991-01-04  NaN
4      000130 1991-01-05  1.1
5      000130 1991-01-06  2.1
6      000130 1991-01-07  NaN
7      000130 1991-01-08  2.1
8      000130 1991-01-09  0.4
9      000130 1991-01-10  NaN
...    ...    ...         ...
```

Important: consecutive nans + alternate nans = 5. So i can have 3 consecutive nans per month inside the 5 nans. And if i already have n nans in a month, i should only add the difference to reach 5 nans. For example if i already have 2 nans in a month i should only add 3 consecutive nans. If i already have 5 nans in the month the code should do nothing with that month.

I tried this:

```
df['PPNEW']=df['PP'].groupby([df['CODE'],df['DATE'].dt.month]).sample(frac=0.984)
```

But i can't get the exact quantity of NaNs (only in percentage and months sometimes have 30-31 days) and i can't get consecutive NaNs.

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does *`df['PP']` by each `df['CODE']`, `df['DATE'].dt.year` and `df['DATE'].dt.month`* mean?

Comment: @Abhyuday Vaish I must group by code, year and month. I want 3 consecutive and 5 non consecutive df['PP'] NaNs by each month of a specific code and year.

Comment: Do the NaN values have to be in random places? Otherwise, you can just set the first five values of each grouping to NaN, leave one as-is and set the next three values to NaN as well.

Comment: @BurningKarl they need to be in random places :/

Comment: I quote "at least 3 consecutive nans and 5 non consecutive nans" implies 3+5=8 while later you say "consecutive nans + alternate nans = 5" implying 3+2=5. They appear mutually exclusive?

Comment: Oh, or it's 3+5 per code AND 3+2 per month?

Comment: Would 5 consective `nan` values satisfy the condition? Or do you need 2 of them to be separate?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly beautiful code, but it does the job assuming that there are no existing NaN in your data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_nans(df, n_consecutive=3, n_alternate=5):
    seq = list(df["PP"].values)
    
    indexes = list(range(len(seq)))
    
    idx = np.random.randint(0, len(seq) - n_consecutive + 1)
    seq[idx : idx + n_consecutive] = ["nan"] * n_consecutive
    if 0 < idx < len(seq) - n_consecutive:
        indexes = indexes[:idx - 1] + indexes[idx + n_consecutive + 1:]
    elif idx == 0:
        indexes = indexes[n_consecutive + 1:]
    elif idx == len(seq) - n_consecutive:
        indexes = indexes[:idx - 1]
    
    for i in range(n_alternate):
        choice = np.random.randint(0, len(indexes))
        idx = indexes.pop(choice)
        try:
            indexes.pop(choice)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            indexes.pop(choice - 1)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        seq[idx] = "nan"
    
    df["PP"] = seq
    return df
```

Here it is the dataframe I tested this function on:

```
>>> df
   CODE        DATE   PP
0   130  1991-01-01  0.0
1   130  1991-01-02  1.0
2   130  1991-01-03  2.0
3   130  1991-01-04  2.0
4   130  1991-01-05  1.1
5   142  2020-12-27  2.1
6   142  2020-12-28  2.2
7   142  2020-12-29  2.1
8   142  2020-12-30  0.4
9   142  2020-12-31  1.1
```

Here it is the final result once you apply the function to each group

```
>>> (df
     .groupby(["CODE", df["DATE"].dt.month])
     .apply(add_nans, n_consecutive=2, n_alternate=1))
   CODE       DATE   PP
0   130 1991-01-01  nan
1   130 1991-01-02  nan
2   130 1991-01-03    2
3   130 1991-01-04    2
4   130 1991-01-05  nan
5   142 2020-12-27  nan
6   142 2020-12-28  2.2
7   142 2020-12-29  2.1
8   142 2020-12-30  nan
9   142 2020-12-31  nan
```

In your case `n_consecutive = 3` and `n_alternate = 2`.

Comment: thanks @edd313 but  n_consecutive + n_alternate = 5. So i can have 3 consecutive nans per month inside the 5 nans. And if i already have n nans in a month, i should only add the difference to reach 5 nans. For example if i already have 2 nans in a month i should only add 3 consecutive nans. If i already have 5 nans in the month the code should do nothing with that month. If this is possible to do i will appreciate if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you want 5 nans in total for each group. Within those 5, 3 are consecutive and 2 are non-consecutive. In your question you say _I want to have at least 3 consecutive nans and 5 non consecutive nans_. This is confusing, would you mind rephrasing it? Anyway, assuming no existing nans you have to input `n_consecutive = 3` and `n_alternate = 2` as you suggest. For the case when existing nans are present you could change the `add_nans` function adding some logic at the beginning. Please post your update once you make progress.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    df = generate_df();
    df = pd.read_csv('row_data.csv')
    df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    df["Year"] = df['DATE'].dt.year
    df['Month'] = df["DATE"].dt.month

    final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CODE', 'DATE', 'PP'])
    for year in df["Year"].unique().tolist():
        year_df = df[df["Year"] == year]

        for code in year_df["CODE"].unique().tolist():
            specific_code_df = year_df[year_df['CODE'] == code]

            for month in specific_code_df['Month'].unique().tolist():
                specific_by_month_df = specific_code_df[specific_code_df['Month'] == month]
                
                full_months = len(specific_by_month_df)
                if(full_months < 28):
                    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, specific_by_month_df])
                    continue
                
                null_counts = specific_by_month_df['PP'].isna().sum()

                if(null_counts == 0):
                    pp_column = list(specific_by_month_df['PP'])
                    for i in range(1, 4):
                        pp_column[i] = NaN
                    
                    rand_index_1 = randint(5, (len(pp_column) // 2) - 1)
                    rand_index_2 = randint(len(pp_column) // 2, len(pp_column) - 1)
                    
                    pp_column[rand_index_1] = NaN
                    pp_column[rand_index_2] = NaN
                    specific_by_month_df['PP'] = pp_column

                elif(null_counts == 1):
                    pass
                elif(null_counts == 2):
                    pass
                elif(null_counts == 3):
                    pass
                elif(null_counts == 4):
                    pass
                else:
                    pass

                final_df = pd.concat([final_df, specific_by_month_df])


    final_df.to_csv("final_df.csv", index=False)
```

This is not complete , but just wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next, it will work if the main conditions are no broken, that is if there are no more than 3 consecutives nan, and more than 5 in total. If you wanna fix those cases use a bunch of if and it will do the job, but this is enough, I think. If you wanted by `'CODE'` just change the `df.groupby([df['CODE'], df['date'].dt.month])` to `df.groupby(['CODE'])`. Let me know if it works ;)

```
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series


def rand(start, stop, *exclude):
    start_date = datetime.now()
    x = randrange(start, stop)
    exc = [0 if i < 0 else i for i in exclude] 
    while x in exc:
        x = rand(start, stop)
        assert datetime.now() - start_date < timedelta(seconds=5), 'Took TOO long!!!'
    return x       


def getPositions(L: list) -> list:
    tot = []
    for x in L:
        if not isinstance(x, list):
            tot.append(x)
        else:
            tot += getPositions(x)
    return tot    


def addNan(values: list, cons_nan: list=[], non_cons_nan: list=[]) -> list:
    temp_non_cons = non_cons_nan[:]
    temp_cons = cons_nan[:]
    while len(temp_non_cons) + len(temp_cons) < 5:
        while len(temp_non_cons) < 2:
            exc = temp_non_cons[:]
            for i in temp_cons:
                exc += [i-1, i, i+1]
            temp_non_cons.append(rand(0, len(values), *exc))
        while len(temp_cons) < 3:
            exc = []
            for i in temp_non_cons:
                exc += [i-1, i, i+1]
            exc += temp_cons
            non_exc = []
            for i in temp_cons:
                non_exc += [i-1, i, i+1]
            if non_exc: 
                for i in range(0, len(values)):
                    if i not in non_exc:
                        exc.append(i)
            try:
                temp_cons.append(rand(0, len(values), *exc))
            except AssertionError:
                break
        else:
            break
        
        temp_non_cons, temp_cons = cons_nan[:], non_cons_nan[:]
        
    for i in temp_non_cons + temp_cons:
        values[i] = np.nan
    return values
            

def countNan(values: Series, x: int = 0) -> list:
    if values.empty or not np.isnan(values.iloc[0]):
        return []
    else:
        temp = x + 1
        return [x] + countNan(values[1:], temp)


def runColumn(values: Series, count:int = 0) -> list:
    if values.empty:
        return []
    else:
        x = countNan(values)
        if not x:
            i = 0
            temp = count + 1
            return runColumn(values[i + 1:], temp)
        else:
            i = x[-1]
            temp = count + i + 1
            return [[i + count for i in x]] + runColumn(values[i + 1:], temp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the DF to analyze:
    # ...
    df['PP'] = df['PP'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == 0 else x)
    groups = df.groupby([df['CODE'], df['date'].dt.month])
    list2concat = []
    for i, group in groups:
        nans_positions = runColumn(group['PP'])

        # 'nans_positions' will be a list like this [[x1, x1+1], [x2], [x3, x3+1, x3+2]]
        # where each 'x' will be a position with a nan
        nans_positions.sort(reverse=True)
        if len(nans_positions ) > 2:
            nans_positions  = (nans_positions [0], getPositions(nans_positions [1:])) 
        group['PP'] = addNan(list(group['PP']), *nans_positions)
        list2concat.append(group)

    nan_df = pd.concat(list2concat, ignore_index=True)
    print(nan_df)
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Ricardo Garcia Saez :/

Comment: Could there be more than 5 nan initially?? @Javier